# Angular ui-router submits form and redirects page

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, forms, angular-ui-router

**Question has been updated according to contributions from users MarkWatson and sdfacre**

Upon the click of a button, I want to submit a form and show the results on a different page. However, my code isn't working.

I am using ui-router to change the states:

```
$stateProvider.state('first', {
    url: '/first',
    templateUrl: '/first.html',
    controller: 'MainCtrl',
}).state('second', {
    url: '/second',
    templateUrl: '/second.html',
    controller: 'MainCtrl',
})
```

Note that I have already injected state into my controller. Here I also injected state into my submit function:

```
$scope.submitForm = function() { 
    server.submitForm($scope.input1, $scope.input2)
    .success(function(data) {
        $scope.results = data;
        $state.go('second');
    }).error(function(err) {
        console.log(err);
    });    
};
```

HTML form:

```
<form name = "myform" ng-submit = "submitForm()">
    ...

    <button type = "submit" ng-click="validationFunction()" class="btn btn-default">Submit and go to another page</button>
</form>
```

I do not want to put " $state.go('second'); " into the validationFunction because I only want the redirect to happen if the form is submitted, not when it is validated.

Currently, the data is not showing up on the second page as expected.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you move to the second page you are accessing a different $scope, so the data will not be there. Register a service with angular:

```
app.factory('GlobalState', [function() {
   return {
       results: null
   };
}]);
```

Then inject GlobalState into your controller and set $scope.results = GlobalState.results (more on this later):

```
app.controller('MainCtrl', function MainCtrl($scope, $state, ..., GlobalState) {

   $scope.results = GlobalState.results;
```

When you submit the form instead of setting $scope.results set GlobalState.results:

```
.success(function(data) {
    GlobalState.results = data;
    $state.go('second');
```

When you go to the second page $scope.results should be set based on this line from above:

```
$scope.results = GlobalState.results;
```

Comment: I got a "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier" on the line "var results: nil;" in the factory. How do I avoid this?

Comment: Should be `null`. Was in iOS mode I guess. Edited the answer.

Comment: still the same error with null, I think it's saying that it's never seen results before.

Comment: Get rid of `var`, too. Sorry, did this from memory.

Answer (score 2):

remove $state from $scope.submitForm = function($state);

that's not injection, it just overrides the $state variable.

Comment: thanks, I have updated my question to reflect the new error I get "ReferenceError: $state is not defined" when I remove $state from $scope.submitForm = function($state)

Comment: did you inject it in your controller? please show your controller code.

Comment: Can you add your controller definition? If you are injecting it then I am surprised you are seeing that error. Also, you should move `$state.go('second');` into success:

`.success(function(data) {
   $scope.results = data;
   $state.go('second');`

Comment: @sdfacre you are right, I had a typo. I had state instead of $state when I injected it in the controller. That fixed the redirect. However, the data isn't showing up in the second page.

Comment: @MarkWatson do you mean I should simply move where I put $state.go('second');?

Comment: The data is still not showing up in the second page, this is after I moved it @MarkWatson

Comment: See my answer above.

Comment: depends on how you retrieve the data in your second page. @MarkWatson has shown you an option in his answer.

Answer (score 0):

there are two way you can do it the right way would be to create different controller and you can send the data to the next page in url like this

```js
$stateProvider.state('first', {
    url: '/first',
    templateUrl: '/first.html',
    controller: 'MainCtrl',
}).state('second', {
    url: '/second/{data}',
    templateUrl: '/second.html',
    controller: 'someCtrl',
})
```

and frm controller u can do this

```js
$state.go('second', { 'test': data});
```

and on the other controller yo can access the url param data like this

```js
  app.controller("someCtrl",['$scope','$stateParams','$http',function($scope,$stateParam,$http){
  
    $scope.somevar=$stateParam.test;
  
     }]);
```

the second approach that I wont suggest is u can put the data in $rootScope

Answer (score 0):

i think first you should validate the form using ng-messages or html5 validation rather than using validate function, to check if form is valid  or not

```
<form name = "myform" ng-submit = "myform.$valid ? submitForm(): ''">
...

<button type = "submit" class="btn btn-default">Submit and go to another page</button>
```

by this what will happen is ,the form will be validated in DOM only, and in the submit form you can redirect to second page